# Find missing elements in a list created from a sequence of consecutive integers with duplicates in O(n)

Tags: python

This is a [Find All Numbers Disappeared in an Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-all-numbers-disappeared-in-an-array/) problem from LeetCode:

> Given an array of integers where `1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n (n = size of array)`,
> some elements appear twice and others appear once.
>
> Find all the elements of `[1, n]` inclusive that do not appear in this array.
>
> Could you do it without extra space and in O(n) runtime? You may
> assume the returned list does not count as extra space.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Input:
> [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]
>
> Output:
> [5,6]
> ```

My code is below - I think its O(N) but interviewer disagrees

```
def findDisappearedNumbers(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    results_list=[]
    for i in range(1,len(nums)+1):
        if i not in nums:
            results_list.append(i)
    return results_list
```

Comment: This is O(n^2), not O(n), since the line ```if i not in nums``` actually has to do a linear search in order to find whether it exists in the array or not. You can read up more on the general approach to this problem on a very similar Leetcode problem, https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/.

Comment: How about `set(range(1, len(arr)+1)) - set(arr)`?

Comment: Thanks NikhilChatterjee. Chris that is very clever, is that O(N)?

Comment: set is O(n). So if you have a set of range (1, n) and set of arr, the diff of that will be the missing values. So yes, @Chris is right

Comment: @Chris That's clearly not "without extra space".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement an algorithm where you loop through each element of the list and set each element at index i to a negative integer if the list contains the element i as one of the values,. You can then add each index i which is positive to your list of missing items. It doesn't take any additional space and uses at the most 3 for loops(not nested), which makes the complexity O(3*n), which is basically O(n). [This site explains it much better and also provides the source code.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-positive-number-missing-from-an-unsorted-array/)

**edit**-  I have added the code in case someone wants it:

```
#The input list and the output list
input = [4, 5, 3, 3, 1, 7, 10, 4, 5, 3]
missing_elements = []

#Loop through each element i and set input[i - 1] to -input[i - 1]. abs() is necessary for 
#this or it shows an error
for i in input:    
    if(input[abs(i) - 1] > 0):
        input[abs(i) - 1] = -input[abs(i) - 1]
    
#Loop through the list again and append each positive value to output list
for i in range(0, len(input)):    
    if input[i] > 0:
        missing_elements.append(i + 1)
```

Comment: This will not be O(n). For each value of i, you need to iterate thru the list to find out if i is in the list. Thats O(n^2)

Comment: It should be O(n). For each value i in the list, you set a[x] to a negative value where x is a[i]. So it just loops through once and isn’t a nested for loop, and thus the time complexity should be O(n). The rest of the loops add another O(n) per loop but you just add the O(n)‘s together since none of the loops are nested, which would not give more than O(3n) or O(4n). That is pretty close to O(n).

Comment: got it. Yes,  it is O(n). My code based on your logic is : `lst = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]`   `x = [i for i in range (1,len(lst)+1)]`   `for i in lst: x[i-1] = -1`   `print ([i for i in x if i != -1])`

Comment: The list x is not needed, and the value can't be any negative number. It has to be -list[i - 1] (My bad). I have edited the the answer to contain the code that I have tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the implementation. it is best not to use `list` as a variable as it is a python built-in method.

Comment: My bad. I just quickly typed out the code and forgot about that stuff. I'll change the name.

Answer (score 4):

For me using loops is not the best way to do it because loops increase the complexity of the given problem. You can try doing it with sets.

````py
def findMissingNums(input_arr):
    
    max_num = max(input_arr) # get max number from input list/array

    input_set = set(input_arr) # convert input array into a set
    set_num = set(range(1,max(input_arr)+1)) #create a set of all num from 1 to n (n is the max from the input array)

    missing_nums = list(set_num - input_set) # take difference of both sets and convert to list/array
    return missing_nums
    
input_arr = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1] # 1 <= input_arr[i] <= n
print(findMissingNums(input_arr)) # outputs [5 , 6]```
````

Comment: If were to use len(lst) instead of max(lst), then you reduce the time complexity. len(lst) is O(1) vs max(lst) is O(n).  In this case, we already know that the list contains n values and  n is the size of the array. So we should try and use len(lst).

Comment: you're thinking right but if the letters are repeated the max will not be equal to length. example [1,2,2] max is two but the length is 3.

Comment: input_arr = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]

Answer (score 1):

Use hash table, or dictionary in Python:

```
 def findDisappearedNumbers(self, nums):
     hash_table={}
     for i in range(1,len(nums)+1):
        hash_table[i] = False
     for num in nums:
        hash_table[num] = True
     for i in range(1,len(nums)+1):
        if not hash_table[i]:
           print("missing..",i)
```

Comment: @FishingCode, the first for loop is O(N), the second for loop is O(N), and the last one too. So time complexity is O(3*N)

Comment: Thanks, i thought of that but it says to not use extra space

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
a=input() #[4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]
b=[x for x in range(1,len(a)+1)]
c,d=set(a),set(b)
print(list(d-c))
```